# How does this definition of curl make sense?

Tags: calculus, vectors

In our maths textbook, curl is defined as $\text{curl} \textbf{F} = \nabla \times \textbf{F}$.  If the $\nabla$ operator isn't a vector, but an operation on a vector, how can it be an operand of a cross product?

$$\textbf{F} \in \mathbb R^3 \\ (\nabla) \in \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 \\ (\times) \in \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 \\ \nabla \times \textbf{F} \in \mathbb R^3$$
This seems as silly to me as:
$$2 \in \mathbb R \\ \text{sin} \in \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \\ (+) \in \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \\ \text{sin} + 2 \in \mathbb R$$
Obviously, you can't treat sine as a number and add it to 2.  How come you can treat functions as numbers in the definition of curl?  Finding this cross product makes less sense, since you have the determinant of a matrix containing 3 vectors, 3 functions, and 3 scalars.

Comment: $\mathbf F: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ and $\nabla \times: (\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3) \to (\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3)$ (notice that $\nabla \times$ is *one* operator).  Thus $\nabla \times \mathbf F: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ as expected.

Comment: Well if $(\nabla \times)$ is one operator, how is _it_ defined? I understand that if $\textbf F = P\textbf i + Q\textbf j + R\textbf k$ then $\text{curl}\textbf F = (\frac{\partial R}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z})\mathbb i + (\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial R}{\partial x})\mathbb j + (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x})\mathbb k$, but doesn't that come _from_ the $\nabla \times \textbf F$ definition?

Comment: See [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation).

Comment: @user290808 You can use that as the definition: $\nabla \times$ is defined as the *operator* (a thing that eats a function and spits out another function) given by $P\mathbf i + Q\mathbf j + R\mathbf k \mapsto \left(\partial_yR-\partial_zQ\right)\mathbf i + \left(\partial_zP-\partial_xR\right)\mathbf j + \left(\partial_xQ-\partial_yP\right)\mathbf k$.  That's not a very good definition because it's basis-dependent, but that's another matter (see the [limit integral definition](http://mathinsight.org/curl_definition_line_integral) of curl for a basis-*in*dependent definition).

Comment: @MattDickau Seems like section [1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Del_operator) of that article addresses this question directly. I'd +1 you for it if I had more rep :-P

Comment: [Chapter 4 in This Book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0780334132.html) addresses your question and more. Tai presents an original approach to the "Del Operator" conundrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the cross product.

For two vectors, $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$,
$$\vec{A}\times\vec{B}=\begin{vmatrix}\mathbf{i}&&\mathbf{j}&&\mathbf{k}\\A_x&&A_y&&A_z\\B_x&&B_y&&B_z\end{vmatrix}$$
If we were to replace these instead with $\vec{\nabla}$ and $\vec{F}$, then we have
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}=\begin{vmatrix}\mathbf{i}&&\mathbf{j}&&\mathbf{k}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\F_x&&F_y&&F_z\end{vmatrix}$$
If you were to combine the components of $\vec{\nabla}$ with the components of $\vec{F}$ in the same way as you would two vectors in the cross product, you will get the correct formula for the cross product - assuming you are using Cartesian coordinates.

This has simply been carried on as notation, a handy way of remembering the formula - it's not by any means formally correct. The $\times$ doesn't denote a separate operation, like the cross product does.

The same thing goes for the divergence, $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{F}$. The $\cdot$ shouldn't be taken as an extra operation on $\vec{\nabla}$ or $\vec{F}$; the formula for divergence simply happens to be extraordinarily similar to the formula for the dot product.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer, but Matt's comment seemed to help my confusion more, however this answer explains abuse of notation for $\nabla$ by using [abusive of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Cross_product) for the determinant.  I'll accept it as a warning that not everything in the textbook is formally correct.  And, you're right; it's easier to remember than the formal definition.

Comment: @user290808 I'm glad it helped. And Matt's point is an excellent one.

Answer (score -1):

$
\mathrm{\nabla}
$
can be regard as a vector
$
\left({\frac{}{\mathrm{\partial}{x}}\mathrm{,}\frac{}{\mathrm{\partial}{y}}\mathrm{,}\frac{}{\mathrm{\partial}{z}}}\right)
$
to participate in calculation